# Is it possible to convert map tick into feature class easily?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have to design a lot of map into the following layout for forest carbon inventory survey:

--There will be a grid set in the map 30 second by 30 second (these are straight lines crossed)
--There  will exist points (on the grid intersection) symbolized based on the layer land use type which is another polygon layer

Please see image--
[image: Map Demand]

> > I tried fishnet in both arc map and X tool, but there is no way to set 30 seconds interval exactly-- i think this is error prone
> >
> > I tried Exporting and using Arc Scan to get the point-but problem is Arc scan limited to poly-line not point what i need.
> >
> > After georeferencing, i tried to use spatial join this point layer with land use layer and symbolized accordingly

Is there any easy way to do this..

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "there is no way to set 30 seconds interval exactly" with Create Fishnet are you just referring to that being 1/120 of a decimal degree = 0.00833333333333?  In comparison to your ArcScan workaround I would have thought that this was plenty accurate enough.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should look into **[Grid and Graticule Layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/What_are_grid_and_graticule_layers/00s900000004000000/)**:

> Grid and graticule layers are composed of point, line, polygon, and
>   annotation feature classes. These feature classes comprise the
>   different parts of a grid, including the neatline, border, grid lines,
>   **grid ticks**, and coordinate labels, and since they are features, they can be edited with the standard editing tools and masked using
>   the common masking tools.

Near the bottom of this page it says:

> Grid definition files can be created or modified using the grid
>   designer available with the Esri Production Mapping extension. Grid
>   definition files can be shared, and additional grid formats will be
>   made available through the online resource centers.

This does not say that you have to have the Esri Production Mapping extension to use **[Grid and Graticule Layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/What_are_grid_and_graticule_layers/00s900000004000000/)** but it sounds like you may need someone with such a license to make the particular one that you are after, which can then be shared with you.

If this is the only way forward for you to try and meet this requirement then I recommend that you post a new Question along the lines of ...

"Has anyone with Esri Production Mapping made a Grid definition files for this fine grained grid specification?".

Note: I am not an **Esri Production Mapping extension** nor **[Grid and Graticule Layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/What_are_grid_and_graticule_layers/00s900000004000000/)** user

Comment: But if  I want to get the fine grained test of grid modification, I have to buy Production Mapping!!!

Comment: If is use 1/120 of a decimal degree = 0.00833333333333 as fishnet parameter output net net does not match accurately with the grid.In production mapping suite there is a tool called grid designer that is used to modify built-in grids and create customised grid..

Answer (score 3):

you should try fishnet in a geographic coordinate system in order to have "exact" coordinates in degrees. However, if you are interested in evenly spaced points, I would suggest to create your grid of point using excel , then you make XY event layer based on this grid.

Comment: Sorry for belated response, I have tried it but it is also time consuming relatively since i have to complete almost 4000 maps.